# PhpStorm and PSR-12, how can I add it as default coding style?

Tags: php, phpstorm

> [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/meta/) is an extension of
>   PSR-2, and therefore also an extension of PSR-1. The basis of PSR-12
>   is PSR-2 and therefore a list of differences is provided below to
>   assist with migration but it should be considered as an independent
>   specification.

From the php-fig site. Long story short, while not mandatory, it covers more code cases than PSR-2.

I'd like to use it in PhpStorm. Unfortunately, by default, storm doesn't offer this option.
At predefined styles you have a fairly comprehensive list, but not comprehensive enough.

[image]

Of course, I can always define the style myself doing it by hand, but that doesn't strike me as a good idea. Mostly because I WILL miss something and if there are any updates to the PSR I can't easily update it. Not to mention I can't share it properly with my team. Except maybe exporting my .idea folder.

I googled around for a plugin or something of that sort but came up empty handed.

Comment: Check PHPstorm for a plugin that does this.

Comment: I did. Nothing of relevance was found.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot add custom entry there as a user unless you write a plugin that will do that.

[WI-48160](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-48160) / [WI-45330](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-45330) -- watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

The implementation of these tickets will bring a new entry in that list.

---

**UPDATE 2019-10-08:** PSR-12 Code Style preset has been added for 2019.3 version (currently in EAP stage).

Comment: I did actually vote on it. Looking forward for it to get implemented. But as phpstorm updates go, it can take a while. In the meantime I want a workaround of sorts. Given that there is one.

Comment: Manually set the available formatting options then. But considering that some options are simply not yet implemented in current IDE version (see linked tickets in aforementioned WI-45330 ticket), you would not be able to set up it all.

Comment: @Andrei Updated answer with correct ticket number (which is about actually creating such predefined Code Style). As you can see in [WI-45330](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-45330) there are quite a few related tickets that needs implementing that would make it possible to format the code to adhere PSR-12

Comment: It is present now in PHPStorm 2019.3

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2019/08/php-annotated-august-2019/

Answer (score 17):

**PHPStorm Steps for setting coding style to PSR**

> Navgate to **Preferences>Editor>Code Style>PHP**

Click on "Set From" link and select PSR12.

Click ok to save the chages

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can now add it from the dropdown, must've changed some time in the past 2 years.
[image]